# I cannot load a large size table to SQL platform

Tags: sql, datetime, file-upload

The Google SQL platform sent an error message: the DATETIME format with "AM" in the values are invalid. Excel cannot load all the data to manipulate. How do I fix this problem to be able to load the table to SQL platform?

I have open Excel to reformat the DATETIME values to lose the "AM/PM" indicator. However, I am unsure if all the data has been reformatted and when loaded to Google SQL platform, the DATETIME values are all wrong. I want to find a way to solve this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

1. Create a raw table declaring all columns as varchar or at least those columns which are giving errors.
2. Then try to transform the data as per the final schema.

   - As it seems, data has garbage, it will give error.
   - Need to find those garbage records and update manually  or find a pattern which will help to update garbage records.

SQL will allow to manipulate/view large data set based on underneath hardware.